# How to set default call audio output to earpiece when connected to bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, calls, bluetooth-audio, android-wear

My phone is connected with a bluetooth watch. Which has in built speakers. I can make and receive calls from my watch. Now whenever I receive a call my call audio output is sent to my watch speakers. After picking up the phone I can change it to receive output to my phone's earpiece but this is annoying to do everytime I receive a call. Is there a way to force my phone not to transfer incoming call audio to bluetooth?

P.S. I can disable Phone Audio from my bluetooth profile but then I am not able to make calls or see who is calling me from my watch.

Comment: If you cannot see who is calling without the audio profile being enabled then it's an issue with your watch. All android watches I have used can display the caller without using the audio profile. In fact I am surprised that your watch cannot do this.

Comment: I can see who's calling. my goal is not to forward audio to my watch by default. is there a way I can stop forwarding my call audio to my watch?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this yet?

Comment: @JacquesBlom I don't have any solution for this yet. :-/

Comment: Any solution to that on late 2020? I'd like to have a simple thing. My smartphone should ring with my watch. If I answer the call using the watch, I want the audio to go to the watch. If I answer the call using the smartphone, I want to use the smartphone. Whichever device I use to answer the call does seem an evident answer to which device I have at hand ready to answer the call!

Comment: sorry I don't use android anymore but this still surprises me that even after 5 years there's no easy solution to this simple problem.

Answer (score 11):

I was in need of doing this exact thing today. I was forced to figure it out on my own after I couldn't find an answer online. As it turns out, it's easier than I expected.

Open your bluetooth settings, find your device, and click the settings icon for that device. You should see some options for the device. Uncheck the "Phone audio" option.

[image: Example]

Comment: the problem with doing this is your smartwatch won't get any incoming call notifications or any display when you get a call. because you turned off the whole phone audio channel. in my case I still want to see who is calling me.